# React Route Path is showing empty page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to get Singleshow in Main and show text in specified path

Singleshow index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SingleShow extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Single Shows</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SingleShow;
```

Main index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Shows from '../Shows';
import SingleShow from '../SingleShow';

const Main = props => (
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Shows} />
        <Route path="/shows/:id" component={SingleShow} />
    </Switch>
);

export default Main;
```

Route exact path works perfectly but when I type `http://localhost:3000/shows/123` in the browser I get an empty page.

When I inspect in Chrome I see only two things:

- **[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...**
- **in Startnull**

Comment: Is the Main component wrapped inside a Router component?

Answer (score 0):

You should use constructor in your SingleShow component

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  // Don't call this.setState() here!
  this.state = { id:this.props.match.params.id};
}
```

then in render

```
render () {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{this.state.id}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I appare that you not need save "id" to state because it provide from props

Answer (score 0):

If you need only render some data, you can use functional components. Its more simple then classes component. For you case in looks like that:

```
const SingleShow = props => (
  <div>
     <p>{props.match.params.id}</p>
  </div>
);

export default SingleShow;
```